# Can flux actions access stores?

Tags: reactjs, flux

Can Flux actions access stores? I recently got a code review comment asking me to pass a certain value in from a React component, instead of getting it from the store directly in the action. This would change Flux's data flow from this:

```
View->Action->Dispatcher->Store-|
  ^-----------------------------<
```

to this

```
View->Action->Dispatcher->Store-|
  ^------^----------------------<
```

It seems to me that, because all data changes are still going through the dispatcher, that the data flow still goes in the intended direction, updates are still atomic, annd the flow is still easy to reason about. Could there be any drawback?

Comment: A drawback might be that the store can then be both synch and async, if it gets dependent on the data from the action. It sounds to me that if you have to go back from a store to do an action, one have not done the proper action. BUT I don't think there is any imminent drawback with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An action can access a Store, but it should be a strict read-only operation.

Actions may want to yield a dispatch that is conditional on the content of a store and keeping track of what store content is required to perform the action is **not** the responsibility of the invoking component.